# How do you write redux reducers for wide data types?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm currently working on a project that implements something similar to MS Project - A task management app with very wide task properties.

A super simple definition of a task might be like:

```json
{
    "id": 0,
    "description": "Task 1",
    "work": 8,
    "startDate": 0,
    "assignedResource": "Scott"
}
```

However the expectation is that a task may have 50+ fields eventually.

I'm fairly new to React and React-Redux so forgive me if I'm misunderstanding some simple approach, but I cannot understand how it is expected to write reducer actions for a data type like this.

Here is an example reducer for the above task:

```js
import { createSlice, current } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export const tasksSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'tasks',
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    addTask: (state, action) => {
      state.push(action.payload);
    },
    deleteTask: (state, action) => {
      return state.filter(task => task.id !== action.payload);
    },
    resetTasks: (state, action) => {
      let tasks = action.payload;
      return tasks;
    },
    replaceTask: (state, action) => {
      const taskIndex = state.tasks.findIndex(task => task.id == action.payload.id)
      return {
        ...state,
        tasks: [
          ...state.tasks.slice(0, taskIndex),
          action.payload,
          ...state.tasks.slice(taskIndex + 1)
        ]
      }
    },
    setTaskDescription: (state, action) => {
      state.map(t => t.id !== action.payload.id ? t : { ...t, description: action.payload.description })
    } 
  }
})

export const { resetTasks, addTask, deleteTask, replaceTask } = tasksSlice.actions

export default tasksSlice.reducer
```

I wrote `replaceTask` as a quickhand attempt to just write the needed changes dispatched wholesale. But this feels wrong - I cannot guarantee validation or some mistaken mutation doesn't find its way into the store. On the other hand I cannot fathom having to write an action for every single field of the task.

In constrast it seems most examples want you to write actions like `setTaskDescription`, but that would require me to write a ton of boilerplate.

Is there a standard practice for this I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have tasks like:

```
state = {
 tasks: []
}
```

First find the index:

```
const taskIndex = state.tasks.findIndex(task => task.id == action.payload.id)
```

Now, replace it:

```
return {
  ...state,
  tasks: [
    ...state.tasks.slice(0, taskIndex),
    action.payload,
   ...state.tasks.slice(taskIndex+1)
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks I think you improved on my `replaceTask` action, but my question was: Should I be using full task replacement or individual property updates? If the latter, how can I do this without a ton of boilerplate? (I've updated my Q to be more clear).

Comment: I'm my example, single task is updated ie. With all it's properties and this is the way to go.